# check whether a file is in Desktop folder or not Python

Tags: python

I am using `os.getcwd()` to get user current directory. I want to check whether a file is in Desktop folder or not. But `getcwd()` function only returns
username directory, like this `/Users/macbookair`, but I expect this:

`/Users/macbookair/Desktop`

I am using macOS Big Sur. Any help would be greatly appreciated. THanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.chdir('/Users/macbookair/Desktop')` to change directory and
`os.listdir()` - to list the file names in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os    #os module is helpful in interacting with os using python*
os.chdir("C:/Users/user/Desktop")    #change directory to desired path
print(os.listdir())    #list of files at desired path   

filename = str(input())    #typing name of file to check 
if filename in os.listdir():
        print(True)    #if filename exists 
else:
    print(False)    #if filename doesnot exists
```

Comment: Just `print(filename in os.listdir())`

Comment: The question is to check if that specific file exits in desktop or not.

Comment: I know. I'm saying that you don't need an if statement just to print True/False